# 3cm Worm Found in a Glass of Tap Water - please help identify

Tags: species-identification, species

[image: 3cm Stripy Worm Found in a Glass of Tap Water - please help identify]

3cm Stripy Worm Found in a Glass of Tap Water - please help identify. The worm was found in the beginning of July in a glass of tap water, in Ireland. It was about 3cm long, had a round shape and was moving quickly. It had no legs.

Comment: Welcome. Don't you by any chance have a better quality picture?

Comment: I don't have a better picture unfortunately...

Comment: You need stereo microscopes to take a better picture with more resolution.